# Gestionar descargas paralelas o simultaneas con php

Tags: php, destructor

Necesito hacer un script que me limite el numero de descargas simultaneas, es decir si un cliente entra a mi pagina y descarga un archivo mp4 o exe y este comienza a descargarse e intenta descargar otro archivo, el sistema deberia bloquear mas descargas hasta que se descargue el primer archivo.

Tengo este codigo que en teoria me permitiria iniciar la descarga y en ese momento crear una entrada en mi base de datos y el de destructor de la clase eliminaria la entrada que se genera en el metodo send.

```
<?php

class DownloadObserver
{
  protected $file;
  public function __construct($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
  }

  public function send() {
    // -> note in DB you've started
    readfile($this->file);
  }

  public function __destruct() {
     $date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

     $fp = fopen('destructor.txt', 'a+');
     fwrite($fp, $date . PHP_EOL);
     fclose($fp);

    // download is done, either completed or aborted
    $aborted = connection_aborted();
    // -> note in DB
  }
}

$dl = new DownloadObserver("/tmp/whatever");
$dl->send();
```

El problema es que jamas se llega a ejecutar el destructor de la clase alguien me podria ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Que te hace pensar que no pasa por el destructor?  Ejecutado localmente a mi si que me pasa

Comment: he ingresado unas lineas de codigo en el metodo send y en el destructor para escribir en un archivo de txt para verificar cuando se ejecute cada metodo y solo escribe en el archivo cuando se ejecuta el metodo send e inicia la descarga del archivo pero no hace nada despues de eso incluso una vez que el archivo mp4 se termina de descargar

Comment: Pues ponlo en la pregunta... a lo mejor lo que esta mal son esas lineas que usas para depurar la clase

Comment: ya esta agregado el pedazo de codigo que agrego para checar si se ejecuta o no el destructor

Comment: Pues con tu código a mi me funciona tambien. Es decir, siempre me agrega la fecha en el archivo destructor.txt cada vez que lo ejecuto.  Que conste que lo hago en local, ejecutandolo directamente desde terminal usando un archivo zip de otra carpeta de mi sistema como archivo a descargar. O sea, asi:  `php script.php > archivo_descargado_con_readfile.zip`